# std::is_same for a loop statement

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I have two structures with methods returning iterators on begin and end of object collection they own. Methods have different names (this may seem like a bad app architecture, but this is only a simplified model):

```cpp
struct A {
  std::vector<int>::iterator a_begin() { return v.begin(); }
  std::vector<int>::iterator a_end() { return v.end(); }

  std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2 };
};

struct B {
  std::vector<float>::iterator b_begin() { return v.begin(); }
  std::vector<float>::iterator b_end() { return v.end(); }

  std::vector<float> v = { 1.0f, 2.0f };
};
```

I want to write a template function which will iterate over given object (of type A or type B) and do some job with its elements. My approach is:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T t) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
    for (auto it = t.a_begin(); it != t.a_end(); it++) {
      // a lot of stuff
    }
  } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, B>) {
    for (auto it = t.b_begin(); it != t.b_end(); it++) {
      // the same stuff
    }
  }
}
```

It looks a bit ugly for me because of `for` loops bodies are the same. Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: Why do these classes have functions like `a_begin()` and not `begin()`? If they followed standard convention, you could use them without any `if constexpr`, potentially even with range-based loop.

Comment: Why not put that repeated code into a function?  That is the common solution for repeated logic, and would work in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm taking your claim about naming and complexity at face value, so abstract and bridge.

```
namespace detail {
    inline auto foo_begin(A& a) { return a.a_begin(); }
    inline auto foo_end  (A& a) { return a.a_end();   }
    inline auto foo_begin(B& b) { return b.b_begin(); }
    inline auto foo_end  (B& b) { return b.b_end();   }
}

template<class T>
void foo(T t) {
    for (auto it = detail::foo_begin(t); it != detail::foo_end(t); ++it) {
      // the same stuff
    }
}
```

The operation you wanted to vary is the range selection. So a small overload set for the types you care about should do it nicely.

If you do this often, a range adapter may be worthwhile to consider. You can write it by hand, or with C++20's [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange) you may  even leverage this overload set itself.

```
template<class T>
void foo(T t) {
    for (auto &item : std::ranges::subrange(detail::foo_begin(t), detail::foo_end(t))) {
      // the same stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The key concept for iterators is that two iterators define a sequence. That's all there is to it: just use a pair of iterators, rather than a container:

```
template <class It>
void foo(It begin, It end) {
    while (begin != end) {
        // a lot of stuff
        ++begin;
    }
}
```

Now you can call it with a range defined by any kind of container you like:

```
A a;
foo(a.a_begin(), a.a_end());

B b;
foo(b.b_begin(), b.b_end());
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this helps to rethink your problem.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void DoStuff(const T& value)
{
};

template<typename T>
void DoAllStuffFor(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), DoStuff<T>);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2 };
    std::vector<double> v2 = { 1, 2 };

    DoAllStuffFor(v1);
    DoAllStuffFor(v2);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't have vectors, but only iterators, so I fear this doesn't help.